# Codedrops perspective navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using code from this tutorial http://tympanus.net/Development/PerspectivePageViewNavigation/

and wish to edit it slightly. In the demo it has one button which you press and the perspective changes, the only way to get back to a normal view is to click back on the container. I however i want to do this with a fixed menu icon, so first click opens nav, second click hides. Im having trouble linking the second button click to the container click.

I have added a jsfiddle to show what i have, anyone got any ideas? thanks a bunch

```
containerMain.addEventListener( clickevent, function( ev ) {
if( classie.has( perspectiveWrapper, 'animate') ) {
var onEndTransFn = function( ev ) {
if( support && ( ev.target.className !== 'container' || ev.propertyName.indexOf( 'transform' ) == -1 ) ) return;
this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransFn );
classie.remove( perspectiveWrapper, 'modalview' );
document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = docscroll;                   
contentWrapper.style.top = '0px';
};
if( support ) {
perspectiveWrapper.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransFn );
}
else {
onEndTransFn.call();
}
classie.remove( perspectiveWrapper, 'animate' );
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Avh25/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have both ways, click the container or click fixed menu icon both will take it to the normal.

[**Here is Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/Avh25/4/)

```
showMenu.addEventListener( clickevent, function( ev ) {
      if( classie.has( perspectiveWrapper, 'animate') ) {
            var onEndTransFn = function( ev ) {
                 if( support && ( ev.target.className !== 'container' || ev.propertyName.indexOf( 'transform' ) == -1 ) ) return;
                 this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransFn );
                 classie.remove( perspectiveWrapper, 'modalview' );
                 // mac chrome issue:
                 document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = docscroll;
                 // change top of contentWrapper
                 contentWrapper.style.top = '0px';
            };
            if( support ) {
                 perspectiveWrapper.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransFn );
                 }
                 else {
                    onEndTransFn.call();
                 }
                classie.remove( perspectiveWrapper, 'animate' );
      }else{
                ev.stopPropagation();
                ev.preventDefault();
                docscroll = scrollY();
                // change top of contentWrapper
                contentWrapper.style.top = docscroll * -1 + 'px';
                // mac chrome issue:
                document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
                // add modalview class
                classie.add( perspectiveWrapper, 'modalview' );
                // animate..
                setTimeout( function() { classie.add( perspectiveWrapper, 'animate' ); }, 25 );
            }
        });

        containerMain.addEventListener( clickevent, function( ev ) {
            if( classie.has( perspectiveWrapper, 'animate') ) {
                var onEndTransFn = function( ev ) {
                    if( support && ( ev.target.className !== 'container' || ev.propertyName.indexOf( 'transform' ) == -1 ) ) return;
                    this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransFn );
                    classie.remove( perspectiveWrapper, 'modalview' );
                    // mac chrome issue:
                    document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = docscroll;
                    // change top of contentWrapper
                    contentWrapper.style.top = '0px';
                };
                if( support ) {
                    perspectiveWrapper.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransFn );
                }
                else {
                    onEndTransFn.call();
                }
                classie.remove( perspectiveWrapper, 'animate' );
            }
        });

        perspectiveWrapper.addEventListener( clickevent, function( ev ) { return false; } );
    }

    init();

})();
```

Comment: Thanks! still new to the javascript thing, this helps so much

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Avh25/1/

There where two event listeners

```
showMenu.addEventListener( clickevent, function( ev ) {
```

AND

```
containerMain.addEventListener( clickevent, function( ev ) {
```

I simply merged them and use "if" condition from "containerMain" which is:

```
if( classie.has( perspectiveWrapper, 'animate') ) {
```

and the end result was this:

```
    showMenu.addEventListener( clickevent, function( ev ) {
        if( classie.has( perspectiveWrapper, 'animate') ) {
                var onEndTransFn = function( ev ) {
                if( support && ( ev.target.className !== 'container' || ev.propertyName.indexOf( 'transform' ) == -1 ) ) return;
                this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransFn );
                classie.remove( perspectiveWrapper, 'modalview' );
                // mac chrome issue:
                document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = docscroll;
                // change top of contentWrapper
                contentWrapper.style.top = '0px';
            };
            if( support ) {
                perspectiveWrapper.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransFn );
            }
            else {
                onEndTransFn.call();
            }
            classie.remove( perspectiveWrapper, 'animate' );
        }else{
            ev.stopPropagation();
            ev.preventDefault();
            docscroll = scrollY();
            // change top of contentWrapper
            contentWrapper.style.top = docscroll * -1 + 'px';
            // mac chrome issue:
            document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
            // add modalview class
            classie.add( perspectiveWrapper, 'modalview' );
            // animate..
            setTimeout( function() { classie.add( perspectiveWrapper, 'animate' ); }, 25 );
        }
    });
```